# Button doesn't trigger function in API popup, Leaflet routing machine

Tags: javascript, leaflet

```
function addPopup(features, layer) {
        let popupContent = `<p>${features.properties.NAAM}<br>
   ${features.properties.TYPE}<br>
   ${features.properties.OMSCHRIJVING}<br>
   ${features.properties.POSTCODE} ${features.properties.DISTRICT}<br>
    <button type="button" id="btn" >Breng mij naar hier.</button> </p>`
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
    }

var routeControl = L.Routing.control({
        waypoints: [
            L.latLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude),
            L.latLng(51.2194475, 4.4024643)
        ],
        routeWhileDraggin: true,
        geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim()
    }).addTo(mymap);


document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function(){
        routeControl.spliceWaypoints(routeControl.getWaypoints().length - 1, 1, e.latlng);
        mymap.closePopup();
    });
```

I am making a popup with information that I get from an API, underneath the information I have a button. My expectation was that when I press the button my function would work and that my waypoint on the map would change. From what I understand the problem is that I can't get a hold of the button with id=btn to execute my function.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is not loaded in the DOM when you init the clicklistener.

You have to set the clicklistener after the popup is opened.

```
function addPopup(features, layer) {
        let popupContent = `<p>${features.properties.NAAM}<br>
   ${features.properties.TYPE}<br>
   ${features.properties.OMSCHRIJVING}<br>
   ${features.properties.POSTCODE} ${features.properties.DISTRICT}<br>
    <button type="button" id="btn" >Breng mij naar hier.</button> </p>`
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent); 
        layer.on('popupopen',function(e){
           document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function(){
              routeControl.spliceWaypoints(routeControl.getWaypoints().length - 1, 1, e.popup._source.getLatLng());
              mymap.closePopup();
           });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pls check the answer!

Comment: I originally got this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null. After using your code I don't get this error anymore. But now the route doesn't work, when I check the (e.latlng) it is undefined.

Comment: If I update to this.getLatLng() I get this error : Uncaught TypeError: this.getLatLng is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement. If I find it ill let you know. I was using this site as a guideline at the start : https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/interaction/

Comment: ups sorry I updated the answer ... use: `e.popup._source.getLatLng()`